# how to open an "opencv" camera locally, but i am connected to my remote server through jupyter notebook

Tags: sockets, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am running Jupiter-notebook on my local computer but connected to the remote server. I want to open my laptop webcam using "opencv".
Here's what I am trying to do. Hope, it's understandable, although my explanation is bit tacit.

```python
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('52.179.xx.xxx',88xx))

if (cap.isOpened() == False): 
    print("Unable to read camera feed")
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
while(True):
    ret , frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:   
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope this makes sense. 
And I am getting the error as

```python
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Something's wrong with that socket stuff (connection).

Comment: This is python sockets problem, so I am removing opencv tag.

Comment: @zindarod, Hope there's nothing to do with opencv. Thanks though.